# Can't read text in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, opera, microsoft-edge

As you can see in screenshots below, I'm having a hard time reading specific texts in `Google Chrome` and `Opera Browser`.

**It's not a website issue, because:**

- The same web page text in `Microsoft Edge` is showing fine, but looks terrible in Chrome and Opera.
- I've seen this exact same issue in other web sites. e.g `YouTube` , `Google Translate`, `...`

How this can be fixed?

P.S. This issue persists even if I Uninstall/Reinstall Chrome completely.

P.S. Second screenshot is Chrome's settings page

---

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

**3.**

[image]

Comment: It looks like somebody did a crappy job of designing their web page.  Is this the only problem web site?  Have you viewed the page using another browser?  If it's readable in another browser, that's a solution.  That, or if every web site has this problem, would also suggest that it is a browser issue, something we might be able to actually help with.  Otherwise, you could copy the problem text and paste it into a text editor.  It will be readable there.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's not website issue, because:  **1.** Same web page text in `Microsoft Edge` is showing fine, but in `chrome` and `opera` looks terrible. **2.** I've seen this exact same issue with some other web sites.

Comment: If it's only happening in a specific website, which one is it?

Comment: @harrymc I believe It's not a website issue and I've described the reason in my question.

Comment: This is happening in two web browsers, so this is a general problem. This kind of problem usually is caused by some font you have installed being used instead of the right one. Use an extension to find out which font is really used. On Chrome maybe [Font Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-finder/bhiichidigehdgphoambhjbekalahgha?hl=en).

Comment: @harrymc That's it. I installed this extension you've shared. All **Almost Invisible** fonts are from `Roboto` fontFamilly. I just removed `Windows/Fonts/robotothin.ttf`. Everything look fine now. if you'd like to answer this question I'll accept. Thank you.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening in two web browsers, so this is a general problem
having to do with the operating system.

This kind of problem usually is caused by some font you have installed being
used instead of the right one. It is not happening on all browsers, since
the font-choosing algorithms may differ.

Use an extension to find out which font is really used. For Chrome you could use
[Font Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-finder/bhiichidigehdgphoambhjbekalahgha?hl=en).

Once you find the troublesome font, you will need to remove it and restart the
browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have "Helvetica" or "Helvetica Neue" installed.

Helvetica is standard on Mac but not on a PC, the PC uses Arial, web pages force to use "Helvetica Neue" > Helvetica > Arial. If the browser can't find a Helvetica, it uses Arial.
However, if you have a single font from the Helvetica package alone, it will be preferred over Arial, even if it is just the super-slim version.

Solution: Uninstall Helvetica OR install all common Helvetica fonts, e.g. from cdnfonts.com the package helvetica-neue-55.font